# What is an efficient way of determining the number of intersections between several lines defined in Cartesian [x,y,z] space?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, sorting, geometry

I'm trying to efficiently calculate whether any of several curved lines, defined in Cartesian [x,y,z] space, intersect. I have a working algorithm that calculates the intersection of 2 lines - the simplest case.

However, I need to scale up my algorithm to calculate whether any of 100,000 lines do intersect. I am expecting there to be little to no intersections. I was wondering if anyone had any advice as to how to scale up my intersection algorithm (i.e. what is the minimum number of computations I need to run). I'm using MATLAB, but I am interested also in general logic answers.

Each individual line is organised in vector format as follows:

```
V1 = [x1 y1 z1; x2 y2 z2;... ; xn, yn, zn]
```

Comment: You may want to provide the code that you have and create a minimum working example for us to follow... Otherwise, just check if the first line intersects with any other, than the second line with any (but the first)... this is pretty much all about how efficient your code-snippet is (as you will call it over and over again) and if you need to know only that a line is intersected or how often (in the former case, you can `break` the loop after it finds the first intersection)

Comment: Cheers - I thought as much. By this logic the number of intersection computations, N = (Nv^2-Nv)/2. Where Nv is the number of lines.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have use a kd-tree to solve problems like this. Try to access the paper: [K-d Trees for Semidynamic Point Sets by Jon Louis Bentley.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/98524.98564)

In its simplest form it can find the nearest neighbor to each point in massive point sets very fast.

To summarize, all the points are placed into buckets as you build the kd-tree. Then as you search with each point, you descend down into the tree, eliminating half the remaining points at each step with a fast test to see which side of a wall you are on.

With adjustments, you can do point-in-sphere tests, n-nearest-neighbors etc.

For tests that are not conveniently spherical, like triangle intersections and in your case curve-curve intersections, you can create an axis-aligned bounding box around each curve, and as you build the tree you use the center of the AABB in order to partition the space (same as with points), but then you make another pass where you attach a list of the overlapping AABBs to each bucket. Then when it comes to searching the tree for each curve, you end up testing its AABB against buckets it overlap with, and with other curves in those buckets' overlap list. These AABB intersection tests eliminate most of the set very fast (benchmarks in the paper), and then you are left to do your actual curve-curve intersection test on a handful of objects.

You'll get plenty of Google results for kdtree implementations in matlab. Just make sure they can find intersections of objects in bounding boxes.

Comment: smart workaround +1 for thinking outside the box. `knnsearch(...'K',1)` is probably the most convenient implementation if you have the Statistics and Machine Learning Toolbox on hand. But it requires to have the *lines* as points as it does not interpolate between them or can handle mathematical line notations (which weren't part of the question anyway)

Comment: Thank you! I implemented a technique similar to what you recommended.